# Javascript, copying properties and arrays versus a pointer

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So I just ran into this issue, and while i've been working Javascript a while now, I didn't realize what seems to be an innate behavior and I'm hoping you guys can help explain when in this is the case. Consider this:

```
let a = {key1: [1,2,3]};
let b = a.key1;
b.pop(1);
console.log(a); // { key1: [ 1, 2 ] }
```

It appears that instead of `b` becoming a copy of `a.key1` it is infact passing a pointer to the original data. This causes any changes that I make to `b` reflect up to `a.key1`. So my question is where can I read more about this behavior, does this apply for copying solely `objects`, or does it apply to other things (e.g.`arrays`, `strings`).

This is somewhat alarming to me considering code I've written in the past not being aware of this and leaving landmines for myself to find later...

Comment: `b` is an array, and `pop()` mutates that array. (There's only one array in memory with your code, but both `a.key1` and `b` refer to it)

Comment: Thanks for the related article. I'll dive in.